# How can I use any json or array or any js file in .testcaferc.json?

Tags: json, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have created one file .testcaferc.json that contains all configuration information like browser name, specs, timeouts etc. I want to fetch the configuration data from file so that I have to change the information at only one place

I want to store all these information in single file, I tried, js, json and array. But I can not import all above format files in my .testcaferc.json, when I press Alt+F8 I see the error "**Expected a JSON object, array or literal**"

Is there any way I can import json, array or js data in .testcaferc.json?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

The `JSON` format doesn't support any import directives. The TestCafe configuration file (`.testcaferc.json`) is a simple JSON file. So, the TestCafe configuration file doesn't support such functionality.

To achieve your goal, you can transform the existing `.testcaferc.json` file before test running: load data from various sources and add/replace values for the appropriate data fields.

Also, there is a [suggestion](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/5109) in the TestCafe GitHub repository, which will make your scenario easier to implement. Track it to be notified about its progress.